# How can I disable Javascript click function if link starts with #

Tags: javascript, html

How can I run this code on all links URL except links that start with `#` like bootstrap collapse, modal links etc.?

```
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function() {
        $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
        $(this).after("<div class='se-pre-con text-center pp500'><i class='fa fa-list fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw text-color1'></i></div>").fadeIn(); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the first character to make sure it isn't #.

```
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href").substr(0, 1) != "#") {
      $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");
      $(this).after("<div class='se-pre-con text-center pp500'><i class='fa fa-list fa-spin fa-5x fa-fw text-color1'></i></div>").fadeIn();
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not` selector in jquery. Example:

```js
$(function(){
$("a:not([href='#'])").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
alert("You clicked me!");

      });
    });
```

```css
a { display: block }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="link">Click Me!</a>
<a href="link">Click Me Also!</a>
<a href="link">Me Too!</a>
<a href="#">Don't CLick me please!</a>
<a href="#">Don't Click me!</a>
```

note: preventDefault stops the link from opening

Answer (score 0):

Just use CSS negation and prefix attribute selector:

```js
    $('a:not([href^="#"])').click(...)
```